# Can not brew uninstall

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm new to the community and I have just started to learn how to code. So, what I was first trying to do is to change the installation path of the packages of Homebrew to my External Disk (Llyne DExt), but failed. So now I can't brew uninstall because I get this:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Llyne:Llyne DExt llyne$ pwd
/Volumes/Llyne DExt
MacBook-Pro-de-Llyne:Llyne DExt llyne$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
MacBook-Pro-de-Llyne:Llyne DExt llyne$ brew uninstall
Usage: brew uninstall, remove, rm [options] installed_formula|installed_cask
[...]

Uninstall a formula or cask.

  -f, --force                      Delete all installed versions of formula.
                                   Uninstall even if cask is not installed,
                                   overwrite existing files and ignore errors
                                   when removing files.
      --zap                        Remove all files associated with a cask.
                                   May remove files which are shared between
                                   applications.
      --ignore-dependencies        Don't fail uninstall, even if formula is a
                                   dependency of any installed formulae.
      --formula, --formulae        Treat all named arguments as formulae.
      --cask, --casks              Treat all named arguments as casks.
  -d, --debug                      Display any debugging information.
  -q, --quiet                      Make some output more quiet.
  -v, --verbose                    Make some output more verbose.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.

Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 installed formula or installed cask argument.
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: See the "Usage" part. The command is `brew uninstall <name of formula or cask>`, as described in the error "*This command requires at least 1 installed formula or installed cask argument*". Are you trying to uninstall a specific package or the entire Homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to uninstall Brew? try this

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`

Comment: I appreciate so much Peter!

Comment: Don't have enough reputation. Once I do, I will!